# Sun Grid Engine job dependency behaviour

Tags: dependencies, sungridengine

I am using the Sun Grid Engine job/task dependency mechanism (-N option and -hold_jid option) to submit (qsub) a number of dependent jobs to the cluster. I would like job b depending on job a not to start if job a exits with non-zero return/exit code and have job b and all jobs depending on b removed from the queue.

However, the behaviour I observe is that if job a exits with any code except 100 (as described in man page), job b will switch from hqw to qw and eventually r as soon as job a is finished. If I make job a exit with code 100, Sun Grid Engine seems to figure this out and job a appears as Eqw and job b stays in hqw forever.

I am using sub -b y and my command is a simple Python script with sys.exit(100) to mimic the exit code behaviour.
Is there any direct way of doing this or do I need to poll grid engine with qstat and qacct -j  and manually qdel jobs that shouldn't run because prior jobs haven't completed successfully, i.e haven't returned with exit code 0?

Thanks